# How do you send JSON from the server to an EJS file and parse it?

Tags: json, node.js, validation, express, ejs

I added a webform to my Node.js/Express app and I'm trying to setup the validation and sanitization for it but I'm running into parsing issues. I'm using the Express-Validator middleware and Node-Validator module for my validation and sanitization. So far, it looks like I installed them correctly and I was also able to output the stringified version of the JSON I want to parse on my template.

**Here is what my code looks like:**

**Server.js**

```
var express          = require ('express'), 
    organization     = require('./routes/organizations'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    check            = require('validator').check,
    sanitize         = require('validator').sanitize, 
    Validator = require('validator').Validator;

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.logger('dev')); /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
  app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
  app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
  app.use('/views', express.static(__dirname + '/public/views'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(expressValidator());
    app.use(app.router);
});


app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});


app.get('/submit-organization', function(req, res){
  res.render('submit-organization', { 
            title: 'Form Validation Example is currently Valid',
            message: '',
            errors: ''
        });
});

//Post
app.post('/submit-organization', function(req,res){

    /**
    req.onValidationError(function (msg) {
        var errors = req.validationErrors();
        var mappedErrors = req.validationErrors(true);
        console.log("errors are: " + mappedErrors);
        res.render('submit-organization',{errors: msg});
    });

    req.check('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();   
    req.check('description', 'A description is required').notEmpty();        
    **/

    req.assert('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();   
    req.assert('description', 'A description is required').notEmpty();     

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    var mappedErrors = req.validationErrors(true);

    //console.log(mappedErrors);
    res.render('submit-organization',{errors: mappedErrors});     





});

app.listen(3002);
console.log('Listening on port 3002...');
```

**submit-organization.js**

```
<% include header %>
<div class="pure-u-1">
    <div style="color:red">
            <%- JSON.stringify(errors.name) %>
    </div>
    <form action="/submit-organization" method="post"  class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Submit Organization</legend>

            <p>An organization can be anything from a club to that running group you might be in</p>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="My Organizaton Name">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select id="category" name="category">
                    <option>category 1</option>
                    <option>category 2</option>
                    <option>category 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
                <input id="keywords" type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="running, excerise, beer, blah">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="website">Website</label>
                <input id="website" type="text" name="website" placeholder="www.example.com">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea id="description" name="description" style="width:400px;height:100px;"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div id="meeting-times">

                <h4>When</h4> 


                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Monday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="monday-venue" type="text" name="monday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="monday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="monday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="monday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="monday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Tuesday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="tuesday-venue" type="text" name="tuesday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="tuesday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="tuesday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="tuesday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="tuesday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Wednesday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="wednesday-venue" type="text" name="wednesday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="wednesday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="wednesday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="wednesday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="wednesday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Thursday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="thursday-venue" type="text" name="thursday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="thursday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="thursday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="thursday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="thursday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Friday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="friday-venue" type="text" name="friday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="friday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="friday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="friday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="friday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>


                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Saturday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="saturday-venue" type="text" name="saturday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="saturday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="saturday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="saturday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="saturday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Sunday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="sunday-venue" type="text" name="sunday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="sunday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="sunday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="sunday-endtime" class="time"type="text" name="sunday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Post</button>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<% include footer %>
```

**In the above file, I'm getting the JSON for one of the errors like this: **

```
<%- JSON.stringify(errors.name) %>
```

which outputs JSON for one of the validation errors and it looks like this:

```
{"param":"name","msg":"Name is required","value":""}
```

However, I just want to display the "msg" object on the template, but I get a *TypeError* when I use code like this:

```
<%- JSON.stringify(errors.name.msg) %>
```

Let me know if that is enough information or if you guys need further details on what I'm trying to accomplish here.

- Steve

Comment: So you mean `<%= errors.name.msg %>`?

Comment: Yes, I tried *<%= errors.name.msg %>* but I still get errors. 
TypeError:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TSF2.0/public/views/submit-organization.ejs:4 2| <div class="pure-u-1"> 3| <div style="color:red"> >> 4| <%= errors.name.msg %> 5| </div> 6|....

Comment: I think you need to check in your template if `errors` is actually populated. But to make sure, can you edit your question and post the entire error message (including stack trace)?

Answer (score 0):

@robertklep,

It is being populated. Thanks for your help, but I finally figured this out. I was looking at it all wrong, because I was thinking I could write code in my EJS template for looping through the mapped errors. Instead of writing this code (which I don't think is possible because I tried just about everything I could think of) I created a variable for each validation error in my server.js file and then passed them to my EJS template via JSON. Here is my final code if anyone is interested:

**server.js**

```
var express          = require ('express'),
    dbConnection = require('./models/dbConnection'), 
    organization                 = require('./routes/organizations'),
    home                         = require('./routes/home'),
    expressValidator             = require('express-validator'),
    check                        = require('validator').check,
    sanitize                     = require('validator').sanitize, 
    Validator                    = require('validator').Validator;

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.logger('dev')); /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
  app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
  app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
  app.use('/views', express.static(__dirname + '/public/views'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(expressValidator());
    app.use(app.router);
});


app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');


app.get('/',home.getOrganizations);


app.get('/submit-organization', function(req, res){
  res.render('submit-organization', { 
            title: 'Form Validation Example is currently Valid',
            message: '',
            errors: ''
        });
});

//Post
app.post('/submit-organization', function(req,res){

    req.assert('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();   
    req.assert('description', 'A description is required').notEmpty();     


    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    var mappedErrors = req.validationErrors(true);

    var myerror1 = mappedErrors.name.msg;
    var myerror2 = mappedErrors.description.msg;
    res.render('submit-organization',{errors: {error1: myerror1, error2: myerror2}});     

});

app.listen(3002);
console.log('Listening on port 3002...');
```

**submit-organizations.ejs (sorry, I mistakenly wrote "submit-organizations.js" in my original question):**

```
<% include header %>
<div class="pure-u-1">
    <div style="color:red">
        <ul>
            <li><%- JSON.stringify(errors.error1) %></li>
            <li><%- JSON.stringify(errors.error2) %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <form action="/submit-organization" method="post"  class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Submit Organization</legend>

            <p>An organization can be anything from a club to that running group you might be in</p>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="My Organizaton Name">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select id="category" name="category">
                    <option>category 1</option>
                    <option>category 2</option>
                    <option>category 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
                <input id="keywords" type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="running, excerise, beer, blah">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="website">Website</label>
                <input id="website" type="text" name="website" placeholder="www.example.com">
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea id="description" name="description" style="width:400px;height:100px;"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div id="meeting-times">

                <h4>When</h4> 


                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Monday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="monday-venue" type="text" name="monday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="monday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="monday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="monday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="monday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Tuesday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="tuesday-venue" type="text" name="tuesday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="tuesday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="tuesday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="tuesday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="tuesday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Wednesday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="wednesday-venue" type="text" name="wednesday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="wednesday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="wednesday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="wednesday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="wednesday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Thursday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="thursday-venue" type="text" name="thursday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="thursday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="thursday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="thursday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="thursday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Friday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="friday-venue" type="text" name="friday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="friday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="friday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="friday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="friday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>


                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Saturday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="saturday-venue" type="text" name="saturday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="saturday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="saturday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="saturday-endtime" class="time" type="text" name="saturday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

                <div class="inline-block">
                    <div class="day"><label>Sunday</label></div>
                    <label>@</label> 
                    <input id="sunday-venue" type="text" name="sunday_venue" placeholder="Some Place"> 
                    <input id="sunday-starttime" class="time" type="text" name="sunday_starttime" placeholder="8:00 AM"> <label>-</label>
                    <input id="sunday-endtime" class="time"type="text" name="sunday_endtime" placeholder="9:00 AM">
                </div>

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Post</button>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<% include footer %>
```

Comment: Please disregard my comment about how you can't loop through JSON objects in EJS. You can do this, actually, and there's a good example of it on their [website] (http://embeddedjs.com/). I applied the code they have for looping through a list of supplies. I still had to get each validation error in server.js file from the mappedErrors variable and then pass those values to my EJS template using JSON (which I matched up to the JSON example that the homepage for EJS)